# Load and read a csv file with php

Tags: php, csv, filestream

I want to download some content in csv format. It is stored online in a csv file. I can not just read the content. I first have to download the file, open and then read it.

Is there a way to open it directly? Or do I have to first load/upload it on my server and then open it like a classic file?

Comment: please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+csv+php is answering your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can open directly using `fopen` and `fgetcsv`

However, this feature sometime is restricted for security concern, and you can read the 
details via the documentation

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Another drawback of open directly, if the page is processed many time, which mean it generate lots of network transfer overhead, and potentially slow down your page generation time.

Ideal case will be download into your server, and repeated use local disk file for processing, that will save some network bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [fgetcsv()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [str_getcsv()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: Link-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow.