# PHP code for handling a csv file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load and read a csv file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354517/load-and-read-a-csv-file-with-php)

```
,,"CS Speech Drop Call Rate %","CS64 Drop Call Rate %","DCR_PS_R99_Eric","DCR_HS_P7_Eric","pmNoNormalRabReleasePacketUra","pmNoNormalRabReleasePacket","pmNoNormalRbReleaseHs","pmNoSystemRbReleaseHs","pmNoSuccRbReconfOrigPsIntDch","pmChSwitchSuccFachUra","pmNoSystemRabReleasePacketUra","pmNoSystemRabReleasePacket","pmUpswitchFachHsSuccess","pmNoSystemRbReleaseEul","pmNoNormalRbReleaseEul","pmEulToDchSuccess","pmPsIntHsToFachSucc","pmNoSystemRabReleaseSpeech","pmNoNormalRabReleaseSpeech"
"W38314011","9 Nov 11",0.44 %,,1.36 %,0.20 %,14,4657,4116,12,51,362,11,36,1136,8,1608,57,1604,1,226
,"10 Nov 11",0.75 %,,1.14 %,0.17 %,12,7593,6984,15,99,427,19,47,1226,10,2559,37,1735,2,265
,"11 Nov 11",0.31 %,0.00 %,0.94 %,0.19 %,11,7613,6951,17,66,232,13,39,1000,14,2411,41,1593,1,325
,"12 Nov 11",0.00 %,,1.33 %,0.37 %,9,5507,4850,25,53,335,12,51,993,22,2470,50,1586,0,325
,"13 Nov 11",1.14 %,0.00 %,1.69 %,0.21 %,12,7158,6440,18,47,291,12,48,1191,15,2839,59,1781,3,261
,"14 Nov 11",0.00 %,,1.59 %,0.25 %,19,6351,5660,20,97,348,13,51,1349,17,2732,54,1918,0,286
,"15 Nov 11",0.25 %,,0.95 %,0.15 %,19,8994,8289,17,125,340,14,42,1870,15,3539,48,2548,1,400
"W38314021","9 Nov 11",0.53 %,,1.17 %,0.14 %,51,13429,11715,24,125,916,32,88,2676,16,5087,520,4126,3,563
,"10 Nov 11",0.63 %,0.00 %,2.06 %,0.21 %,53,16527,14381,44,147,953,52,163,3441,29,6123,549,5232,4,632
,"11 Nov 11",0.23 %,,0.63 %,0.13 %,63,15273,13069,27,221,1112,50,99,3514,17,5952,544,5318,2,876
,"12 Nov 11",0.13 %,0.00 %,1.65 %,0.13 %,34,15788,13911,25,146,1052,49,125,2818,17,5828,512,4330,1,741
,"13 Nov 11",0.22 %,,2.76 %,0.15 %,46,13034,11555,25,111,848,31,124,2310,12,5443,386,3514,1,463
,"14 Nov 11",0.37 %,,3.59 %,0.14 %,47,14621,12934,27,153,1131,41,177,3172,17,6410,581,4489,3,805
,"15 Nov 11",0.38 %,0.00 %,3.62 %,0.14 %,42,15307,13323,27,174,866,55,194,2948,22,7244,548,4623,3,785
```

I have a csv(5 MB) file like this. Two empty "," signifies two headings, one for Value and one for date. 
From second row onwards the value is given only for one day of the week other 6 days of the week are empty in first column. Then the value is given for the the first day of next week and so on..........

**I need a php code to copy the value for all 7 days of the week.**

Comment: in the future, please put some effort into attempting to solve the problem before posting on SO looking for someone to hand you code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `fgetcsv()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php