# Convert a string to an array - PHP

Tags: php, string, csv, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load and read a csv file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354517/load-and-read-a-csv-file-with-php)

I have the following string:

```
Mr,Tom,Jones,Add1,Add2,"Add3,Add3 extra",Town,County,postcode,99999,888,777
```

I am tring to get the string into an array that looks like the below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mr
    [1] => Tom
    [2] => Jones
    [3] => Add1
    [4] => Add2
    [5] => "Add3,Add3 extra"
    [6] => Town
    [7] => County
    [8] => Postcode
    [9] => 99999
    [10] => 888
    [11] => 777
)
```

if you explode the string by "," it splits array item 5 into 2 parts which I am trying to avoid.  The original data comes from a CSV.

Ultimatly I am trying to import a CSV and create a new DB on the fly with the headers and file content against the correct headers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> fgetcsv — Gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields

Comment: [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) could do that work too.

Comment: True but if he has a file with the data (CSV mostly means "i have a file") then he should use fgetcsv().

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = str_getcsv( 'Mr,Tom,Jones,Add1,Add2,"Add3,Add3 extra",Town,County,postcode,99999,888,777', ',', '"' );
```

This will get you to an array with what you want.

[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

From [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

> str_getcsv — Parse a CSV string into an array